# Python getting ranks of elements in list weird behavior

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values, I want to get the ranks of these values in the list x

This is the code that I tried:

```
x = [4,7,9,10,6,11,3,15,2]
seq = sorted(x, reverse=True)
index = [x.index(v) for v in seq]
```

and I don't understand why it gives this output : [6, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 0, 8] instead of the right order.

EDIT: sorry, the right order is [7,5,3,2,1,4,0,6,8] (decending order of the values in x by index)

EDIT2: I fixed it. Sorry, lack of sleep :p.

Comment: and what is the  right order?

Comment: what’s your desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate over the sorted list `seq` and find the index of the original list `x` instead:

```
x = [4,7,9,10,6,11,3,15,2]
seq = sorted(x, reverse=True)
index = [x.index(v) for v in seq]
```

`index` becomes:

```
[7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 0, 6, 8]
```

Using the `index` method in a loop makes the solution unnecessarily *O(n^2)* in time complexity, however. You should instead consider creating a dict that maps items in `x` to their indices, and since the lookup of a dict key costs *O(1)* in average, doing it in a loop would thus cost only *O(n)*:

```
x = [4,7,9,10,6,11,3,15,2]
indices = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(x)}
seq = sorted(x, reverse=True)
index = [indices[v] for v in seq]
```

Comment: Thanks! Love the dictionary solution.